# GO-BAN game, evaluation function

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write an evaluation function for the goban game, but I'm having trouble, because I don't understand how to implement this algorithm. Suppose I have an 8x8 board, where white = 1, black = -1, empty cell = 0, but then what...
How to describe the problem in general? I would be very grateful for hints.

There are two players. Each player gets 12 checkers. The player who gets the white checkers puts one of them on any of the squares of the board. Then a black checker is placed in any square of the board. Then a white checker is placed and so on in turn.

The goal of the game is to place five of your checkers in a row in a straight line - horizontal, vertical or diagonal.

The player, seeing that his opponent has put three of his checkers in a row on a straight line, must now put his checker in a line near them. If he misses this moment and the opponent put in a row of four checkers, then he will not be able to prevent the fifth, as he will not be able to overlap the row, acting only at one end.

When the opponents have placed all their 12 checkers, they begin to move them one by one, striving for the same goal - to place five of their checkers in a row in a straight line.

You can move your checkers to any side, but only to the adjacent square, not occupied by a checker.

Each resulting combination of five checkers is recorded (to avoid repetition) and brings the player one point. The player who gets the first 10 points wins.

What are your ideas for writing this function? Where should I start? I've been sitting for two days and haven't really thought of anything (and I've never written a game before)...

Answer (score 1):

It's generally better to start from as simple an evaluation function as possible and refine it once the algorithm is working.

The simplest possible evaluation function would be:

- `1` means I've won
- `-1` means my opponent won
- `0` means no one has won yet.

In C++:

```
constexpr int win_score = 10;

int eval(const game_state& state) {
   if( state.p1_score() == win_score) {
    return 1;
  }

  if( state.p2_score() == win_score) {
    return -1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

In this case, since this is a score-based game, a slightly more subtle evaluation function could be to say "More score than the opponent is better":

```
int eval(const game_state& state) {
  return state.p1_score() - state.p2_score();
}
```

But even then, there might still be value in using a binary win vs lose function. After all, winning `10-9` is not any more preferable than winning `10-0`, and being up `5-0` doesn't mean anything if you can't pull off a win from there.

You could combine the two like so:

```
constexpr int win_score = 10;

int eval(const game_state& state) {
  int val = return state.p1_score() - state.p2_score();

  if( state.p1_score() == win_score) {
    val += 100;
  }

  if( state.p2_score() == win_score) {
    val -= 100;
  }

  return val;
}
```